# Remove and unbind subviews in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

I am using Backbone 1.1.2 and I found that some weird behaviour of my app was probably due to zombieviews. I read the ["Run! Zombies!" article from Derick Bailey](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) but found out later that this was written for an older version of Backbone (0.9 if I am correct).

Then I found that for the newer Backbone version it was enough to do a .remove() on views to kill them properly (because the events bound with ListenTo would automatically be removed by a call to StopListening).

In my app I have a global view that at some point creates two subviews. When clicking a reset button (within the global view) these views should be rerendered (but probably first removed/unbound to prevent zombieviews).

So what I did was appending the subviews to a list that was accessible by the global view. In the initialize function:

```
this._views = []; // empty list
```

and when rendering the subviews I added them to the list

```
v = new app.gameView();
this._views.push(v);
```

Just before rerendering the subviews I call a function cleanUp that loops through the list of subviews and does a .remove() followed by an .unbind() for each subview:

```
_.each(this._views, function(view){
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
});
this._views = []; // empty the list for next use
```

My question is twofold:

1. Is calling .remove and .unbind enough to prevent zombieviews?
2. Is adding the subviews to a list within the global view the proper way of doing this?

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: You're doing the right things in my eyes!

Comment: I've been confused after reading several questions about this, but now I've got mine working by using your approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, simply calling `remove()` and `unbind()/off()` is enough to prevent "zombies" hanging around. The only thing I would add is that if the parent view (*the one that contains the subviews inside of `this._views`*) is being referenced from another part of your application, then you have to make sure that you remove those references by simply assigning those variables to null.

It is totally fine to have a `this._views` array inside of the parent to save its subviews in. However, as your application grows you might want to create some sort of Subview Manager and a Core View that all other views inherit from.

Here is what I've done in the past; I hope it helps:

**CoreView**:

```
// Probably all views should inherit from CoreView.
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  'subviews'
], function($, Backbone, Subviews) {

  var CoreView = Backbone.View.extend({
    $main: $('#main'),

    // Create an empty `subviews` property on all views.
    constructor: function() {
      this.subviews = new Subviews(this);

      // Since we're overriding `constructor` here, 
      // we need to delegate to Backbone
      Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },


    // Views should be attached to the DOM only with the `attach` method to have the right events thrown. 
    // Attach the view's element only if it's not already in the DOM.
    attach: function() {
      if (!this.isAttached()) {
        this.$main.append(this.el);
        this.trigger('dom:attach');
      }

      return this;
    },


    isAttached: function() {
      return $.contains(document.body, this.el);
    },


    // Remove each view's subviews and clean up various properties before 
    // calling Backbone's remove() method.
    remove: function() {
      if (this.subviews.size()) {
        this.subviews.removeAll();
      }

      // Remove the DOM element (jQuery makes sure to clean up DOM element's data)
      Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);

      // Fire a helpful `dom:detach` event when the view is removed from the DOM.
      this.trigger('dom:detach');
      this.off();

      return this;
    }
  });


  return CoreView;
});
```

**Subview Manager** (*not complete*):

```
// Simple Subview Manager
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone'
], function($, Backbone) {

  function Subviews(view) {
    this.self = view; // this view
    this._entries = {}; // its subviews
  }

  Subviews.prototype = {
    constructor: Subviews,

    add: function(name, viewInstance) { ... },
    has: function(name) { return !!this._entries[name]; },
    get: function(name) { return this._entries[name] && this._entries[name]; },

    // By default the subview manager tries to replace an element with
    // a `data-subview` attribute with the actual subview element.
    attach: function(name) {
      // In the parent view's template you would have: `<div data-subview="child1"></div>`
      var $subViewOutput = this.self.$('[data-subview="'+name+'"]');

      if (this._entries[name] && $subViewOutput.length) {
        $subViewOutput.replaceWith(this._entries[name].render().el);
      }
    },

    // When removing a subview we also have to remove it from
    // this view's `subviews` property.
    remove: function(name) {
      if (this._entries && this._entries[name]) {
        this._entries[name].remove();

        // Cleanup
        this._entries[name] = null;
        this._entries = _.omit(this._entries, name);
      }
    },

    removeAll: function() {
      if (this.size()) {
        _.each(this._entries, function(view) {
          view.remove(); // it will call remove() in CoreView first
        });
      }

      this._entries = {};
      this.self = null;
    },

    size: function() {
      return _.size(this._entries);
    }
  };


  return Subviews;
});
```

**Ordinary View**:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  'templates',
  'views/coreView',
  'views/childView'
],
function($, Backbone, templates, CoreView, ChildView) {

  var Widget = CoreView.extend({
    tagName: 'section',
    id: 'widget123',
    template: templates.widget123,

    initialize: function() {
      this.subviews.add('child1', new ChildView());

      this.on('dom:attach', function() {
        // When the parent is inserted into the DOM also insert its child1
        this.subviews.attach('child1');
      });
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      return this;
    }
  });


  var instance = new Widget();
  instance.render().attach(); // attach() comes from CoreView
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. My app is still relatively small, but I am thinking ahead a little so your approach might indeed become very handy in the (near) future to apply for my project. I'll keep it in mind. I see the `define` which means you are using require.js right? That's on my bucketlist to add to the project also.

Comment: Usually for Backbone projects I use RequireJS for more modular code and for managing dependencies. I also use HandlebarsJS for templates as it allows you to precompile them, something which Underscore's template helper does only at run time.

Comment: And the precompiled templates will be a boost for performance, right? That's good to know, I will look into those as well! Thanks again!

Comment: @Lim That's the idea, however performance should be measured to really know how much of a boost you'll get though. Also precompiled templates are better because they can be kept in separate files. In production you can minify & concat them into one file.

Example templates: https://github.com/vasilionjea/email-templatizer-fancy/tree/master/src/templates

The `.handlebars` files are the templates (_not compiled yet_) and they have a syntax that looks like this: `{{content}}`. The JS files with the same names are the templates that you'll use in your code (_compiled_).

I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Great, I am surely gonna have a look at this. I appreciate your help, thanks again!